# I accedentaily erased my level.dat file and I dont have a backup of the world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So my world got corrupted and I tried to create a new world with the same level.dat and etc. But when i checked it was gone. Is there any way to recover my world?

Comment: When you checked where? How did the world get corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is a backup of the world in **.minecraft/backups**. You can also try to recover the world using a file recovery tool.